# JQuery .on("mouseover") method not working for IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am attempting to return the value for a dynamically populated select option on mouseover. As you can probably tell by the ID, the select option is created by an ASP.NET listbox.

```
$("#MainContent_LocationListBox").on("mouseover", "option", function () {

    alert($(this).val());
});
```

This method works in Chrome but not IE 11.

I have been trying other's peoples solutions for similar problems with no luck.

What I've tried:

- Different versions of JQuery (currently 1.8.3)
- The `.live` method
- `$(document).on("mouseover", "option", function ()`
- `$("#MainContent_LocationListBox option").on("mouseover", null, function ()`
- Looping through the select options and binding mouseovers to each
- Adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` (the advice of several articles I found)

I've also tried `$("#MainContent_LocationListBox option:hover").val()` which works but very inconsistently.

I've turned on Internet Explorer debugging but no errors are returned.

Comment: It's sloppy and wasteful to put your delegated event listeners on the `$(document)` selector; you should put them as close to the targets as possible.

Comment: Like the id of the element maybe @Robusto? As in what the OP's code already does?

Comment: I'm still confused as to why developers have to continue supporting a browser that even Microsoft refuses to support anymore.

Comment: @Kendo Because private corporations have spent millions building in-house proprietary applications for IE that aren't going away any time soon?

Comment: @ScottMarcus That's true yes, never considered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mousemove` instead of `mouseover`. The code below works in Internet Explorer, Firefox and Chrome:

**UPDATE**: Since the test on Windows 10 failed, I added a `setTimeout` call, following a suggestion give [here](https://roslindesign.com/2011/05/04/detecting-the-hover-css-selector-style-in-jqueryjavascript/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var prevValue = null;

    $("#MainContent_LocationListBox").mousemove(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var val = $('option:hover', $("#MainContent_LocationListBox")).val();

            if (typeof val !== 'undefined') {
                if (val !== prevValue) {
                    console.log(val); // To be replaced by actual processing
                    prevValue = val;
                }
            }
            else {
                prevValue = null;
            }
        }, 0);
    });
});
```

When debugging mouse events, I prefer logging values in the console (which can be displayed with <kbd>F12</kbd>) than popping up `alert` boxes.

Comment: I believe you when you say this works in IE, it just doesn't work for me (Win10 IEv11). I've tried different JQuery versions, different meta tags, resetting IE, different document modes and user agent strings. There are 0 errors in the console. My issue seems to be ":hover" returns a value of "undefined" 99% of the time.

Comment: I tested on Windows 7. The code works for the other browsers on your Windows 10?

Comment: I updated my answer. The timeout is 0 in my example. If it does not work, you may try with a larger value.

Comment: This works! I'm guessing that IE get ahead of itself when extracting the value and the timeout gives it a little hesitation?

Comment: Something like that, yes. You can see the explanation in the article where I found that trick (https://roslindesign.com/2011/05/04/detecting-the-hover-css-selector-style-in-jqueryjavascript/). Strangely, the trick was given for old versions of IE...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding event delegation to the select option, add it to the select.

```
$("#MainContent_LocationListBox").on("mouseover", function () {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Or if you would rather have event delegation

```
$("section").on("mouseover", "#MainContent_LocationListBox", function () {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

Edit: I think you are mistunderanding how you get the value of from a select box.  With jQuery you can use `$('select').val()` on the select box.

More information on event delegation with jQuery .on() http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This seems to return the value of the select not the individual option. However, the $(this) contains array of the options and their values. I have tried to access this array with something like $(this)[hoveredOptionIndex].val() but have not been able to successfully extract an index.

Comment: @bradyGilley The `value` of a select is what the user selected. If you want the index, you can get it easily with `selectNodeReference.selectedIndex`

Comment: So like $(this)[this.selectedIndex].val()? This seems to return the index for whichever option is selected. I need the index for the hovered option.